# connection can-bus to pc with pci

Tags: compatibility, pci

Hi all I need answer if [this](http://www.mini-box.com/Intel-D2500HN-Mini-ITX-Motherboard) is the same PCI as [this](http://emtrion.de/hicocan_pci_en.php)

On the second product it says PCI/104 and I am not sure if this metal layewr that needs to be outside will fit on this board?

If not can you see on second link product and see which one can fit to my board.

Thank you

Comment: Just because this deals with can-bus doesn't make it an EE question. This sounds purely like a computer hardware question. Your question is simply "I have motherboard A, will daughter board B fit into the motherboard?" That is a Superuser.com question.

Comment: Anyway why shouldn't be compatible? Both are PCI, and what you say only specifies that "is also available" a PCI/104 version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PCI Bus comes in many flavors.  There are some variants that use less pins (I see Compact PCI listed, too), since all of the signals are not always used.  PCI/104 is an industrial variant used in compact installations.  It is not the same as generic PCI.  PCI went through a revision where the 5 volt supply was reduced to 3.4 volt, so even if the card plugs in, it may not work.  This was a few years ago, and most cards have been upgraded (at least there is a warning if it is not true). 
Microsoft's "Hardware compatibility list (HCL)" lists the things that they have tested, but comms boards (other than ethernet) are usually not on the list.

Calls to either manufacturer could yield better results. A second computer with a PCI slot would also sort out some of the compatibility issues.  If you can install it in one, youu could look for the differences in the other.

Comment: How do you mean second computer? So what type of question I need to ask to manufacturer?